# evaluation NLP classifier with annotated data

Tags: annotations, nlp, classification, evaluation

if we want to evaluate a classifier of NLP application with data that are annotated with two annotators, and they are not completely agreed on the annotation, how is the procedure?
That is, if we should compare the classifier output with just the portion of data that annotators agreed on? or just one of the annotator data? or the both of them separately and then compute the average?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the majority vote between annotators is common. Throwing out disagreements is also done.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161228130651/https://lingpipe-blog.com/2016/12/27/ethics-logistic-regression-and-0-1-loss/)'s a blog post on the subject:

> Suppose we have a bunch of annotators and we don’t have perfect agreement on items. What do we do? Well, in practice, machine learning evals tend to either (1) throw away the examples without agreement (e.g., the RTE evals, some biocreative named entity evals, etc.), or (2) go with the majority label (everything else I know of). Either way, we are throwing away a huge amount of information by reducing the label to artificial certainty. You can see this pretty easily with simulations, and Raykar et al. showed it with real data.

What's right for you depends heavily on your data and how the annotators disagree; for starters, why not use only items they agree on and see what then compare the model to the ones they didn't agree on?